# Как создать роль в discord.py, которая будет показываться отдельно от остальных участников в сети?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я делал discord.py проект, и мой бот должен был создавать роль,
которая показывалась отдельно от участников с этой ролью в сети.

[image: Пример]

И вот, я не могу понять, как это сделать. Кто-нибудь знает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого достаточно при создании роли указать параметр `hoist` со значением `True/False`.

Например:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")


@bot.command(name='createrole')
async def command_name(ctx: commands.Context, role_name: str):
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name=role_name, hoist=True)
```

Узнать подробнее про функцию `create_role`, можно в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role).